# Can I do a Parameterized Query containing Geometry Function?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, geospatial

I have an SQL query that goes like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Places (name, latlng)
 VALUES (?, GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)'))");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['name']);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $_POST['lat']);
$stmt->bindValue(3, $_POST['lng']);
$stmt->execute();
```

I have been getting this error:

> 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1048 Column 'latlng' cannot be null'

The `latlng` column is of type `point NOT NULL`. Since the insert works for the following, why would it cause a `NULL` to be inserted for the above?

```
"INSERT INTO Places (name, latlng)
 VALUES (?, GeomFromText('POINT(".$_POST['lat']." ".$_POST['lng'].")'))"
```

So, my question is, can I do a parameterized query containing a geometry function? If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: My guess would be that you have to feed it the entire `'$lat, $lon'` as a value but I can be wrong

Comment: @Pekka, but why doesn't it work in the first case?

Comment: @Pekka, i tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure as I never worked with geometry functions, but I think that 'POINT(? ?)' here is just a string, not a function. You can't just parametrize part of a string, you need to parametrize the whole string. dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Places (name, latlng)
 VALUES (?, GeomFromText(?))"); $stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['name']); $stmt->bindValue(2, 'POINT('.(float)$_POST['lat'].' '.(float)$_POST['lng'].')'); should work and should be safe.

Comment: @XzKto: Yes, I think your explanation is correct. And your solution works too. Can you put it down as an answer so that I can give you the credit. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your query `POINT(? ?)` is just a string, not a function. You can't just parametrize part of a string, you need to parametrize the whole string:

```
$stmt = dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Places (name, latlng) VALUES (?, GeomFromText(?))");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['name']);
$stmt->bindValue(2, 'POINT('.(float)$_POST['lat'].' '.(float)$_POST['lng'].')');
```